# how can I use strtok to use each line as an element?

Tags: c

I have a .txt/.csv file that stores names along with their password as shown below:-

> google, ,9*+=<=2=

> google, ;5290=+:

Each induvial line is a separate entity.
I was trying to make an array with induvial entities as its elements.
I was trying to use strtok with \n as delimiter.
But it throws me the following error.

> test.c:11:21: error: invalid initializer

> char line[100]= strtok(buffer,"\n") ;

> ```
>                ^~~~~~
> ```

Where am I going wrong?
Here is the full block of the particular code:-

```
FILE* fp;
    fp=fopen("storeroom.csv","r");
    char buffer[100];
    rewind(fp);
    fread(buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    char line[100]= strtok(buffer,"\n") ;
    printf("%s",line);
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Also please use https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help to improve the usefulness of the representation of your question.

Comment: `strtok` returns a `char *` that points to the start of the next token. You can't init a  char array with a `char *` . What is it that you actually want the result to be? Do you want to save the pointer that `strtok` returns or do you want to store a copy of the data into an array?

Comment: @kaylum I need to make an array(line here) whose element is a string of each line respectively. so line would be ["google, ,9*+=<=2=","google, ;5290=+:"].

Comment: @xing fgets requires the number of characters to be taken, but the number I want to take isn't the same always, as the lines arent of same length

Comment: *line = strtok(buffer,"\n"); solved the problem. i just needed to use a pointer variable to store it :D. thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You may initialize an array with a braced list. So this declaration

```
char line[100]= strtok(buffer,"\n") ;
```

is incorrect. Moreover the element type of the array is `char` while the initializer expression has the type `char *`.

You could write for example

```
char *line = strtok(buffer,"\n") ;
puts( line );
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char s[] = "Hello\nWOrld!";
    char *p = strtok( s, "\n" );

    puts( p );
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello
```

Comment: hey, can you explain the requirement of puts here?

Comment: @user18025483 There is no such a requirement. But it is simpler to write puts instead of printf with a format string.

Comment: oh! well, the final printf was only put to check. but *line didn't help it shows the same error :(

Comment: @user18025483 It can not issue the same error.

Comment: @user18025483 An error can be issued only if the declaration of the pointer line is placed in the file scope outside a function.